# Не могу выровнить блок

Tags: css3

Речь идёт о блоке с классом `slogan`, если запустить код , то это станет очевидным, так как есть скриншот. Мне посоветовали сделать блоки `form и slogan` шириной по **45%** и `slogan'у` сделать `float:left` не помогло.

```css
body {
  font-size: 120%;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.reg_form {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(109, 162, 180), -1px -1px -1px rgb(109, 162, 180);
  width: 950px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px;
  border-color: #6da2b4;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 10px 25px 0 25px;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
}

.slogan {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-bottom: :500px;
}

.form_label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.options_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.options_menu div:first-of-type {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.options_menu div {
  display: inline;
  border-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.options_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4eb7ff;
}

.options_menu a:hover {
  color: #42629c;
}

.agree_rss {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.reg_info {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.reg_info a {
  color: #4eb7ff;
}

.btn_profile {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0897fd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.slogan h3 {
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 1em
}

.slogan li {
  list-style-image: url("../images/tick.png");
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="reg_form">
  <div class="options_menu">
    <div><a href="#">Войти</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Зарегистрироваться</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form>">
    <form>
      <br><br>
      <label class="form_label">Адрес электронной почты<br/><input type="email" name="mail"/></label>
      <br/>
      <label class="form_label">Пароль<br/><input type="password" name="password"></label>
      <br/> <br/>
      <label class="agree_rss"><input type="checkbox" name="agree_rss" >Я хочу получать рассылку с эксклюзивными предложениями.</label>
      <br/>
      <button type="submit" name="create_profile" class="btn_profile">Создать мой профиль</button>
      <p class="reg_info">Создавая аккаунт , вы согласны с нашими <a href="#">Правилами и условиями</a> и <a href="#">Положением о конфиденциальности</a></p>
      <div class="slogan">
        <h3>Быстро, бесплатно и надежно!</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Вносите изменения в бронирования</li>
          <li>Настраивайте рассылку предложений</li>
          <li>Выигрывайте время</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: а надо так]

Comment: Хотя бы намекни о каком блоке речь...))))

Comment: Речь идёт о блоке с классом slogan ну если запустить код , то это станет очевидным так как есть скриншот.Мне посоветовали сделать блоки form  и slogan шириной по 45% и slogan'у сделать float:left не помогло

Answer (score 1):

1. Уберите эти непонятные `margin-left` и `margin-bottom` у `.slogan`;
2. В классе `<div class="form>">` ошибка;
3. Задайте `.form {display: flex}` и `.slogan {width: 50%;}`;

PS - Уберите все `<br>` - сейчас так не верстают, используйте `margin` или `padding` для отступов.

```css
.reg_form {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(109, 162, 180),
      -1px -1px -1px rgb(109, 162, 180);
  width: 950px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px;
  border-color: #6da2b4;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 10px 25px 0 25px;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
}

.slogan {
  display: block;
}

.form_label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.options_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.options_menu div:first-of-type {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.options_menu div {
  display: inline;
  border-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.options_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4eb7ff;
}

.options_menu a:hover {
  color: #42629c;
}

.agree_rss {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.reg_info {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.reg_info a {
  color: #4eb7ff;
}

.btn_profile {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0897fd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.slogan h3 {
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 1em
}

.slogan li {
  list-style-image: url("../images/tick.png");
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.form {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="reg_form">
    <div class="options_menu">
        <div><a href="#">Войти</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Зарегистрироваться</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <form>
            <br><br>
            <label class="form_label">Адрес электронной почты<br/>
                <input type="email" name="mail"/></label>
            <br/>
            <label class="form_label">Пароль<br/>
                <input type="password" name="password"></label>
            <br/> <br/>
            <label class="agree_rss">
                <input type="checkbox" name="agree_rss">Я хочу получать рассылку с эксклюзивными предложениями.
            </label>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" name="create_profile" class="btn_profile">Создать мой профиль</button>
            <p class="reg_info">
                Создавая аккаунт , вы согласны с нашими <a href="#">Правилами и условиями</a> и <a href="#">Положением о
                конфиденциальности</a>
            </p>
        </form>
        <div class="slogan">
            <h3>Быстро, бесплатно и надежно!</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Вносите изменения в бронирования</li>
                <li>Настраивайте рассылку предложений</li>
                <li>Выигрывайте время</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Версия с `inline-block`

```css
.reg_form {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(109, 162, 180),
      -1px -1px -1px rgb(109, 162, 180);
  width: 950px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px;
  border-color: #6da2b4;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 10px 25px 0 25px;
}

.form_label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.options_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.options_menu div:first-of-type {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.options_menu div {
  display: inline;
  border-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.options_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4eb7ff;
}

.options_menu a:hover {
  color: #42629c;
}

.agree_rss {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.reg_info {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.reg_info a {
  color: #4eb7ff;
}

.btn_profile {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0897fd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.slogan h3 {
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 1em
}

.slogan li {
  list-style-image: url("../images/tick.png");
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.form{
    font-size: 0;
}

.slogan,
form {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 16px
}
```

```html
<div class="reg_form">
    <div class="options_menu">
        <div><a href="#">Войти</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Зарегистрироваться</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <form>
            <br><br>
            <label class="form_label">Адрес электронной почты<br/>
                <input type="email" name="mail"/></label>
            <br/>
            <label class="form_label">Пароль<br/>
                <input type="password" name="password"></label>
            <br/> <br/>
            <label class="agree_rss">
                <input type="checkbox" name="agree_rss">Я хочу получать рассылку с эксклюзивными предложениями.
            </label>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" name="create_profile" class="btn_profile">Создать мой профиль</button>
            <p class="reg_info">
                Создавая аккаунт , вы согласны с нашими <a href="#">Правилами и условиями</a> и <a href="#">Положением о
                конфиденциальности</a>
            </p>
        </form><!--
        --><div class="slogan">
            <h3>Быстро, бесплатно и надежно!</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Вносите изменения в бронирования</li>
                <li>Настраивайте рассылку предложений</li>
                <li>Выигрывайте время</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ладно **br-Ы**, так еще и все по разному)))  `Br BR`...

Comment: @Rogatnev Nikita br были временным решением было влом делать отсупы.Мне было интересно как это сделать без флекс потому , что знаю что это возможно.Получилось только с отрицательным значением margin-top:-300px а margin-bottom не работает.Спасибо что указали на ошибку в присвоении класса.

Comment: @ИванПономарев form и slogan тогда просто инлайн блоками сделайте и все встанет как надо

Comment: или используя position: relative и float: left/right ... но лучше флекс контейнеру и justify-content...

Comment: @ИванПономарев добавил в ответ версию с инлайн блоками